# Getting VSProjectLoader extension as part of dotnet-nunit CLI

Tags: .net, nunit, dotnet-cli

Crossposting from [repo](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/1333), with the added attempt of doing `choco install nunit-extension-vs-project-loader` but still not getting the desired functionality.

I recently installed the Nunit console runner as follows:

```
dotnet tool install -g nunit.consolerunner.netcore
```

It seems to work fine, but it also requires me to manually list out the files containing the tests which is a bit of a disappointment. I was hoping that it would have some built-in automatic test discovery.

On the other hand, I notice there are extension points on it, and one of the extensions appears to be `NUnit.Extension.VSProjectLoader`.

However when I tried to install this as a `dotnet` tool I get an error:

```
Cannot find a manifest file.
For a list of locations searched, specify the "-d" option before the tool name.
If you intended to install a global tool, add `--global` to the command.
If you would like to create a manifest, use `dotnet new tool-manifest`, usually in the repo root directory.
```

Is there a way to get this extension as part of a global install of the `dotnet-nunit` CLI tool? I would prefer not to modify my source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions execute in the runner process. Most existing extensions, including the VS Project Loader extension, were written to run under the .NET Framework and therefore will not load under .NET Core. Your errors in installing it as a tool are primarily due to the fact that it's not a dotnet tool.

The nunit console dotnet tool is somewhat limited in comparison to the full nunit console runner, which runs under the .NET Framework and launches separate processes to run .NET Core tests. It supports multiple test assemblies rather than just one including mixed target runtimes. It is able to load the VSProjectLoader extension as well as all others I know of.

I also answered you on the repo. You might consider asking in one place at a time, since many of the same people answer questions in both places.